# is a bad practice expose the Activity in the XML layout in a MVVM app?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

The general idea is that the XML Layout have a reference to the ViewModel like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="aboutViewModel"
            type="com.app.about.AboutActivity" />
    </data>
```

The question is that if is a bad practique expose too the activity like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="aboutActivity"
            type="com.app.about.AboutActivity" />

    </data>
```

Because sometimes I only need call functions for open or close the activity, and I think that these are not a reason enough to create a new ViewModel.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the *OOB - separation of concerns* then you shouldn't tightly couple the `VM` with `Activity`. Also you don't have to create an new `VM` or to tightly couple your current `VM`, you can just access the activity/context like this:

```
android:onClick="@{(view)->((Activity)(view.getContext()))}"
```

Comment: And how can call a particular function in the activity?

Comment: You should be able to do it with casting, like this: `((YourActivity)(view.getContext()).yourMethod(x)`

Comment: I am using this : `android:onClick="@{(view)->((AboutActivity)(view.getContext()).openAboutWeb())}"` but not work, shot this error cannot find method openAboutWeb() in class android.content.Context, any idea?

Comment: The casting is not working. Looks like you were missing some chars, Could you try this: `android:onClick="@{(view)->(((AboutActivity)(view.getContext())).openAboutWeb())}" `  if this doesn't work, then we need to know what the context is really, maybe use `getActivity`